UINavigationController root view disappears
I am presenting a UINavigationController with this code.
let rootVC  = RootViewController()
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.present(navVC, animated: true)

On RootViewController I am pushing a ViewController with this code. TransparentViewController is half transparent. When this vc is pushed a portion of RootViewController should be visible. But Unfortunately i am seeing that RootViewController is disappearing from background and when I pop TransparentViewController it comes back again.
let vc = TransparentViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Am I missing something here?
